# Find the closure of $\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n+a} |n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A=\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n+a} |n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ ($a$ is some positive real number). I want to find the closure of $A$.
I could show that $B:=A\cup \{0\}\subset \overline{A}$ and now I only need to show that $B$ is closed.
I would like to do this by finding the complement of $B$, but I can't write it down explicitely. I know that it will be a countable union of open intervals, yet I cannot formally write this.
EDIT: I think I found a way to show that $B$ is closed the way I wanted to go about it. Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$, $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+a}$. The subsequence $(x_{2n})_{n\ge 1}$ is decreasing and positive, whilst the subsequence $(x_{2n+1})_{n\ge 1}$ is increasing and negative. Then we may write that $\displaystyle \mathcal{C}_B=(-\infty, x_1) \cup \bigcup_{n\ge 1} (x_{2n-1},x_{2n+1})\cup \bigcup_{n\ge 1}(x_{2n+2}, x_{2n})\cup (x_2, \infty)$, so $\mathcal{C}_B$ is open and we are done. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

To find closure it is enough to find limit points of $A$. Observe that for any $n$ and for all $\epsilon$ the interval $(- \epsilon , \epsilon)$ contains a point of $A$ since $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n+a} = 0$. So $0$ is a limit point of $A$. It is easy to see that there are no other limit points by choosing suitable $ \epsilon$. So closure of $A$ is $\{0\} \cup A$.

Comment: thank you, your solution is nice. I would like to know if it would be possible to do it my way too.

Comment: Yes. My answer is very close to that. To show that $B$ is closed you need to show that it contains all of its limit points. Since $0$ is the only limit point of $A$ and by construction of $B$ we note that $0$ is the only limit point of it by which we can conclude that $B$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you! So, in this case, if we want to explicitely write the complent of $B$ things get pretty nasty.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but could you tell me how to choose that $\epsilon$ in order to conclude that there are no nonzero limit points?

Comment: I think I found a way to do it like I wanted to do it, I added it in my question.